# How to get real-time Twitter follower count for many accounts (for free)?

Tags: twitter

There are several websites that enable you to see the number of followers of an account in real-time:

- https://livecounts.io/twitter-live-follower-counter
- https://mlmcounts.herokuapp.com/twitter/
- https://www.tucktools.com/twitter-realtime

When reaching out to the admin/developer behind some of the above sites **I was told the data is directly sourced from Twitter for free**.

However, when looking at the Twitter API documentation here:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-list

I was able to find the endpoint to fetch follower count. But the endpoint is clearly rate limited. **I am looking to fetch data on 200 accounts on a real-time basis (every second)**. The rate limit (15 per 15min) seems to make this impossible.

So I am a bit stuck on how these websites are able to display real-time follower count data. Is there another endpoint I am unaware of that can be used to stream real-time follower count data? Or is there something else that I am completely missing?

EDIT:

- Specified the volume of data I am looking to fetch.

Comment: What volume of data are you looking at? It’s straightforward to use the Twitter API to request a user profile and check the follower count.

Comment: The websites I listed show real-time follower count - updates every second for thousands of accounts. Personally, I am looking for real-time data on 200 or so accounts.

Comment: I cannot comment on those websites. The Twitter API has specific limits.

Comment: Ah yeah these are probably scraping the site. Ha. Thanks.

Comment: @AndyPiper I think you are right. I looked into it more and there is no way they aren't scraping it/ or using the free version (which results in a delay in data).